# Matching the UID of an IMAP message to a Microsoft.Graph message

Tags: graph, outlook, imap

This is probably an unusual request but I am writing a .NET replacement for a PHP email handling application for a company. This is only required to pick up emails from the default mailbox of a dedicated email address and process the email and any attached documents etc for a centralized documentation system.

I have started writing the application using Microsoft.Graph, however the current system is using IMAP and I need to allow them to run in parallel for a period and therefore if the original application has processed an email my new one needs to know and not duplicate.

The original application stores information about emails that have been processed to ensure they are not duplicated and it keeps track of this using the UID provided by IMAP.

Microsoft.Graph identifies messages with a different id that is unique across the Office365 infrastructure and has no knowledge (as far as I can see) of the aforementioned UID.

I can emulate the original PHP application using MailKit so I am able to retrieve the same UIDs. I am searching for a reliable way to match a message via its UID with the same message retrieved using Microsoft.Graph.

As a longshot I was wondering if there is, in fact, a common link that I have not found.

Comment: There's a tiny chance that the graph ID is available in IMAP via [objectid](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8474), but that extension hadn't been added by O365 when I checked a year or three ago... if not, your only recourse is the Message-ID header field, which is generally unique per message, but is not guaranteed to be so.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - unfortunately the objectid was not available as you suspected. However, I found that the MessageId from IMAP appears to match the InternetMessageId in a message from Microsoft.Graph - the only difference being the Graph version is wrapped in <>, so this looks like a way forward for now.

Comment: Uhm, the one you get via IMAP should also contain <>. If you see it without, I suspect that a bug is stripping it.